# Is there any criterion to determine undetermined form in limits?

Tags: calculus, limits

In calculus, it is told us that these form: $\frac{0}{0}, \frac{\infty}{\infty}, \infty -\infty, \infty\cdot0, 1^\infty, 0^0, \infty^0$ are "Undetermined forms". Can anyone explain that what actually "Undetermined forms" is and what is the criterion to determine it?

Comment: For the first, consider $\frac{x}{x^2},\frac{x}{x}$ and $\frac{x^2}{x}$. If we want the function to be continuous, then we need to assign different values for $x=0$ in each case. Similar considerations apply to the others.

Comment: In the case of $0\over0$, it means you have a function $f(x)$ approaching $0$ divided by a function $g(x)$ approaching $0$ (both as $x$ approaches something). You cannot determine what ${f(x)\over g(x)}$ approaches, based solely on this information; this is what "undetermined form" means. Contrast this with $0\cdot 0$, which must be $0$, regardless of what the functions are; it is a "determined form".